# How to verify non-vanishing Dirichlet L-function?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

In the context of Dirichlet characters mod $k$, I understand that $L(1, \chi) \ne 0$ for each real-valued non principal character $\chi$ mod $k$, with $L(1, \chi) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\chi(n)}{n}}$.

Say I have a general Dirichlet character table for some modulus $k$.

For this table, I'm not sure how to actually verify the result $L(1, \chi) \ne 0$.

I thought that for a Dirichlet character table, all non principal rows must sum to 0? So I'm not sure I see how iterating over each row and summing the real-valued $\phi(k)$ $\chi$s would not also sum to 0?

Apologies if my question is a bit silly, I'm not sure if I fully understand this topic from the book I'm studying from.

Comment: It's not a-priori at all obvious from a character table that (even for the special case of real characters) $L(1,\chi)\not=0$. Your remark about non-principal rows, etc., may be correct (I'm not sure I understand it), but no interpretation of it that I can see really impinges on $L(1,\chi)$. The proofs that $L(1,\chi)\not=0$ are quite different from any enterprise of just looking at character tables.

Comment: You have one principal character $ 1_{gcd(n,k) = 1}$ and $\phi(k)-1$ non-principal characters. For the latter  $\sum_{n=1}^k \chi(n) = 0$ so that $|\sum_{n=kN}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n}| = |\int_{kN}^\infty (\sum_{n < x} \chi(n))x^{-2}dx| < \frac{k}{Nk}$ converges. So all you need is to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{kN} \frac{\chi(n)}{n}$ for $N$ large enough until you get |$\sum_{n=1}^{kN-1} \frac{\chi(n)}{n}| > \frac{1}{N}$